# Mongo conditionally sum values in project pipeline

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to add in a project pipeline where the values are greater than 100, the values are fields inside and object which are part of an array. I have something like this:

Database:

---Clients Collection---

```
client: {
    _id: 1,
    taxID: aldsfkjasdlñfk
    // other stuff
}
```

---Invoices Collection---

```
invoice: {
    _id: 1,
    clientID: 1,
    total: 50
},
invoice: {
    _id: 2,
    clientID: 1,
    total: 150
},
invoice: {
    _id: 3,
    clientID: 1,
    total: 200
}
```

AND THIS IS MY QUERY:

```
{
     $lookup: {
          from: 'invoices',
          localField: '_id',
          foreignField: 'client.id',
          as: 'invoices'
     }
},
{
     $project: {
          id: 1,
          taxID: aldsfkjasdlñfk,
          invoicesAmountGreaterThanOneHundred: {
               $sum: {
                   $cond: { if: { $gte: ['$invoices.total', 100] }, then: '$invoices.total', else: 0 }
               }
          }
     }
}
```

So the output should be:

```
{
     _id: 1.
     taxID: aldsfkjasdlñfk,
     invoicesAmountGreaterThanOneHundred: 350
}
```

I'm using Mongo 3.6.3.

Also in the future I will add a "invoicesAmountLesserThanOneHundred", same method, but for lesser than 100 of course.

Comment: You can use the `$reduce` array operator to arrive at the `invoicesAmountGreaterThanOneHundred` value within the `$project`.

Answer (score 1):

use `$filter` before `$sum`

```
db.client.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "invoices",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "clientID",
      as: "invoices"
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "invoices": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$invoices",
          "as": "i",
          "cond": { $gte: [ "$$i.total", 100 ] }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      id: 1,
      taxID: 1,
      invoicesAmountGreaterThanOneHundred: {
        $sum: "$invoices.total"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/eBuJNrSQiyt)

---

use `$reduce`

```
db.client.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "invoices",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "clientID",
      as: "invoices"
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "invoicesAmountGreaterThanOneHundred": {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$invoices",
          initialValue: "",
          in: {
            $sum: [
              "$$value",
              {
                $cond: {
                  if: { $gte: [ "$$this.total", 100 ] },
                  then: "$$this.total",
                  else: 0
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OEUZrZCktlZ)

Comment: What does double '$' means?

Comment: @SaturdayCalamity [Variables in Aggregation Expressions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/)